# Importing xls ans xlsx files in c# without having office installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, razor

I've got one simple question.

Can I import xls and xlsx file to my web application based on ASP MVC5, using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider without having any version of Microsoft Office installed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The OLEDB provider does not have a dependency on the Excel application.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use EPPlus library for reading (and writing) XLSX files:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

The drawback is it only works with 2007/2010 Excel versions (and I think 2013 also), so it doesn't have support for xls files, only xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I can endorse is [ClosedXml](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/). This is a much more friendly wrapper around Microsoft's OpenXML SDK.
 I'm not familiar with EPPlus, but Closed XML also only supports .xslx.

Answer (score 0):

You can install only the driver if this is possible in your case or use another library that supports reading Excel files and it is not dependent by MS Office installation at all. You can use EasyXLS library that handles both xls and xlsx files:

http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library